# NSNotification not being received in another class

Tags: objective-c, macos, nsnotificationcenter

I'm trying to send a notification from one class to another, but `notificationReceived` never gets called.

AppDelegate:

```objectivec
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
#import "TestManager.h"

@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate>
@end

------------------------------

#import "AppDelegate.h"

@interface AppDelegate ()
@end

@implementation AppDelegate

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    NSLog(@"did finish launching");
    [[TestManager alloc] init];
}
@end
```

Manager:

```objectivec
#import <AppKit/AppKit.h>
#import "TestObserver.h"

@interface TestManager : NSObject
@end

------------------------------

#import "TestManager.h"

@implementation TestManager
- (instancetype)init {
    self = [super init];

    if (self) {
        NSLog(@"manager init");
        [[TestObserver alloc] init];
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(notificationReceived) name:@"testnotification" object:nil];
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)notificationReceived {
    NSLog(@"notification received");
}
@end
```

Observer:

```objectivec
#import <AppKit/AppKit.h>

@interface TestObserver : NSObject
@end

------------------------------

#import "TestObserver.h"

@implementation TestObserver
- (instancetype)init {
    self = [super init];

    if (self) {
        NSLog(@"observer init");
        [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(sendNotification) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)sendNotification {
    NSLog(@"observer post");
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"testnotification" object:nil];
}
@end
```

Comment: `TestManager` starts observing after `TestObserver` posts.

Comment: Right, I had my timer removed in the sample. I edited it just now, so it also has a timer like my actual use case @Willeke

Comment: I tried your code, it works for me. Is the `TestManager` deallocated?

Comment: In my AppDelegate is just use `[[TestManager alloc] init];` in `applicationDidFinishLaunching`. I also put a log in every method and they all get called, except the `notificationReceived`. @Willeke

Comment: I also tried clearing my build folder as well as using Xcode to run it (I use AppCode mainly).

Comment: Please post a complete code example demonstrating the problem.

Comment: I edited the question to include my entire project. It really is just a test project to figure out why `notification received ` never gets logged. @sbooth

Comment: Make `[[TestManager alloc] init];` a property of the AppDelegate? And `[[TestObserver alloc] init]` a property of `TestManager`? I guess objects which are local variables are deallocated too soon...

Comment: Aha! That's interesting. I've had the TestObserver as an ivar already, but not the manager. I have to have the manager as one as well. Thanks @Larme and everyone else!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both `TestManager` and `TestObserver` need to be a property/ivar, or else either one is deallocated too early.